# Process For Code Development With Hadoop And Docker

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, docker, cloudera

I took a course a while back in Hadoop and a VM was setup with everything installed and I was able to use Intellij to write the java code to do MapReduce jobs.

That was all great but I wanted to learn MapReduce and beyond to a greater detail so I was interested in setting something up on my own machine to practice. I saw Cloudera has docker images that allow one to have an installation of the Hadoop ecosystem in some Linux flavor. I am new to docker but that sounded great, especially because they had a multinode option for a pseudo cluster and I didn't need a cumbersome VM.

My question is how does one actually write MapReduce, Spark, or whatever code to be run in the container? On my host machine there are no Hadoop/Spark/etc jars or libraries, that is all in the image, and looking a bit at docker it seems containers are command line driven. So not sure how to use an IDE in an image. So how does one develop code when all the dependencies are in the image?

Comment: I would start with reading documentation of your-favorite-ide™ These days you can be pretty sure that any IDE supports running / testing / debugging with Docker out of the box or using some extensions.

Comment: Ok, I will definitely take a look at that. But just so I'm clear, do you mean most IDEs support using the jars/libraries in a Docker image that don't exist on the host where the IDE is installed?

Comment: No :) Docker will give you only an execution environment.